# Appending to list from raw input

Tags: python

Why does this print me out the list `[None, None, None]` instead of a list with my three inputted answers?

```
options = []

for i in range(3):
    options[i] = options.append(raw_input("enter an option"))

print options
```

Answer (score 7):

Because `list.append` is an in-place method, it does not return anything , and hence it returns `None` , which is what you set `options[i]` with. Example -

```
>>> lst = [1]
>>> print(lst.append(2))
None
```

`None` got printed in above case, since that is what got returned by `lst.append()` .

You do not need to `options[i] =`. Code -

```
for i in range(3):
    options.append(raw_input("enter an option"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also skip the initialization using comprehension:

```
options = [ raw_input("enter an option") for _ in range(3) ]
```